# Microsoft Office automation for Office 365

Tags: automation, office365

I have a few lines of C# code where I control a PowerPoint slideshow, using the Office automation API.

These are the relevant parts of my Software:

First I obtain the Presentation for a given File name. The objPresSet comes from PowePoint.Application():
objPres = objPresSet.Open(pptFileNm, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue);

Then I iterate over all the slides in objPres.Slides and I 
- count the animated Objects in the slide (number of Events in the slides TimeLine.MainSequence where TriggerType is a MsoAnimTriggerType.msoAnimTriggerOnPageClick
- and I read the Slide Title and Slide Notes using s.Shapes[1].TextFrame.TextRange.Text and s.NotesPage.Shapes[2].TextFrame.TextRange.Text

The data is sent to a remote device and I use the ZXing QR DLL in order to create a QR Code for pairing. Based on the collected data, the remote device is sending commands like goto or next. My C# Program is receiving this data over a persistent HTTP Connection. And based on the commands my Program is executing stuff like objSSW.View.Next() The objSSW comes from objApp.SlideShowWindows;

Is it possible to do that with Office 365 and if yes, what is the name of the tool and product stack (or API) for such a task? Sorry if that is a "stupid" question, but the Microsoft products are not realy my field of expertise.

Comment: Can you share the few lines of C# code you are already using? Do you mean you want to control a slideshow in PowerPoint Online (i.e. PowerPoint via a web browser)?

Comment: Well, to be honest, the few lines of c# are a full blown c# Project.

Comment: Yes, I would like to control the PowerPoint Slide Show Online in Office 365. Please take a look at this Video, I am presenting FonPrompt https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7kTR8zLXW8 and thats what I would like to port to Office 365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing an office store add-in, you can control slide progression via the Office JS library.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142185.aspx

Comment: Martin, thank you for your link, this points me to the right direction. May I ask a few details. Is JavaScript the only language I can use for that, or is there better way to migrate my c# code? If you compare the Office automation API to the Office JS library, how big would you say, is the difference?

Comment: Hi, no problem at all. Yes with modern office add-ins, the interaction between your application and office is via an office JS library Your app itself can be written in any web language (MVC, Ruby, Node, PHP whatever), however calls into the office API are only in JS. See more at http://dev.office.com

Comment: I think, this is the answer so far. I am not so sure if I can follow that path with my little Project, to me it looks like as if it is more a "writing new" then porting and it would introduce a lot of technology I have never seen before. However, I will definitly look a bit more into this.

Comment: I'm glad this helps. Modern office add-ins are really very simple. Just web pages framed inside office with a cool JS library to do the office interaction, check it out at dev.office.com. Either way, I'm glad I helped you :)